# How to hide a Preference in xml android?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preference, android-preference-v14

I should hide a preference in xml. Here is an example.

Instead of removing the entire functionality, I need to hide the second preference which is `top_level_connected_devices` as key in xml. I am using android 10.

```
    <PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:settings="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:key="top_level_settings">
    
          <Preference
                android:key="@string/category_key_wireless"
                android:title="@string/interface_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_interface"
                android:order="-120"
                android:fragment="com.android.settings.InterfaceSettings"/>
    
       <Preference
            android:key="top_level_connected_devices"
            android:title="@string/connected_devices_dashboard_title"
            android:summary="@string/summary_placeholder"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_homepage_connected_device"
            android:order="-110"
            android:fragment="com.android.settings.connecteddevice.ConnectedDeviceDashboardFragment"
            settings:controller="com.android.settings.connecteddevice.TopLevelConnectedDevicesPreferenceController"/>
  </PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: I do realise that the original question was asked about Android 2.3, however that info is still applicable to Android 10.

Comment: oops. Sorry. Thank you.